# How to make a javascript action by URL attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I am playing with a very simple [jquery modal windows](http://thefinishedbox.com/files/freebies/alertbox/index.html). It opens the modal windows by clicking on

```
<a href="#" id="clickMe">Click Me</a>
```

How can I make this javascript action by adding an attribute to the URL, e.g. index.php?q=clickMe or index.html#clickMe

I mean when visiting the webpage of index.html (with q=clickMe or #clickMe), loading the page with opened modal. In other words, the attribute plays the role of CLICK on id="clickMe" for jQuery.

Comment: not an answer but I'm wondering why do you have to do the clicking after you got the url param? can you not just do the modal directly on that after you got the param?

Comment: Yes, I just want to have the modal when the url has a given param. This is indeed identical to click. I want to display the modal if visiting index.html#something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to handle the QueryString or URL Hash in the document.ready().
Here is an example of handling the hash `#clickMe`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if (window.location.hash == "#clickMe") {
    //open modal
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

first i would get a jquery plug in for reading querysting variables - like [getUrlParam](http://www.mathias-bank.de/2007/04/21/jquery-plugin-geturlparam-version-2/)

then, you can do it in script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(document).getUrlParam("activate-click").length > 0) {
    $("#clickMe").click();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use `jquery.url` plugin.